# Looking to loop this script? Python 3

Tags: python, morse-code

```
import time
morse = {'a': '.-',     'b': '-...',   'c': '-.-.', 
        'd': '-..',    'e': '.',      'f': '..-.',
        'g': '--.',    'h': '....',   'i': '..',
        'j': '.---',   'k': '-.-',    'l': '.-..',
        'm': '--',     'n': '-.',     'o': '---',
        'p': '.--.',   'q': '--.-',   'r': '.-.',
        's': '...',    't': '-',      'u': '..-',
        'v': '...-',   'w': '.--',    'x': '-..-',
        'y': '-.--',   'z': '--..',

        '0': '-----',  '1': '.----',  '2': '..---',
        '3': '...--',  '4': '....-',  '5': '.....',
        '6': '-....',  '7': '--...',  '8': '---..',
        '9': '----.', ' ': '          '}
print ("""
================================================================================
                      English to Morse Code Translator
================================================================================""")
time.sleep(2)
print ("")
msg = input('''What would you like translated? please use lower-case letters.
:''')
print ("")
for i in msg:
    print(morse[i])
```

I want to loop it right after the msg input, so it would ask what I want translated after after it translates the first thing for me.

Comment: You can loop forever by indenting a block, and putting `while True:` at the top (not indented as far).

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:  



    msg = input('''What would you like translated? please use lower-case letters.:''')
    print ("")
    for i in msg:
        print(morse[i])
```

to give the user a chance to quit the program:

```
while True:  



    msg = input('''What would you like translated? please use lower-case letters.:''')
    print ("")
    for i in msg:
        print(morse[i])
    userstatus = input('Would you like to go again?(y or n): ').lower().strip(' ')
    if userstatus not in('y', 'ye', 'yes'):
        sys.exit()
```

note you would have to import sys with this example for sys.exit() to work